# On you or on yourself?

Tags: grammar

Don't be too hard on **you/yourself**; it was a difficult test.

I am not sure I will say, "Don't be too hard-"; "on you" or "on yourself"

Comment: Reflexive, so "yourself". But in the interest of making this a more valuable learning experience, what made you uncertain?

Comment: The subject of *you v yourself* has recently been extensively discussed on ELU [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/600425/did-king-charles-iii-use-the-pronoun-myself-correctly)

Answer (score 2):

When talking to another person and referring to actions of others on them we say "you", eg "they do that to you". When referring to their own actions we say "yourself", eg "you did it to yourself".